# AssertionError javax.jms.JMSException on maven build for scala project

Tags: scala, maven

I am getting below error on maven `clean install` of the scala project

```
[ERROR] error: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: javax.jms.JMSException
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1410)
[INFO]  at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.initialize(Symbols.scala:1576)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseExceptions$1(ClassfileParser.scala:976)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.scala$tools$nsc$symtab$classfile$ClassfileParser$$parseAttribute$1(ClassfileParser.scala:845)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseAttributes(ClassfileParser.scala:1005)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseMethod(ClassfileParser.scala:591)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.scala$tools$nsc$symtab$classfile$ClassfileParser$$queueLoad$1(ClassfileParser.scala:474)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$$anonfun$parseClass$1.apply$mcV$sp(ClassfileParser.scala:484)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseClass(ClassfileParser.scala:489)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parse(ClassfileParser.scala:134)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader.doComplete(SymbolLoaders.scala:293)
[INFO]  at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$SymbolLoader.complete(SymbolLoaders.scala:211)
```

And this is the last line of the build error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (default) on project
```

How ever I am able to run the project but failing in build cycle.

I am unable to figure it out why. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: can you provide the maven pom.xml and full error?

Comment: Hi ... I resolved this after close observation of the dependency versions. There was more than one scala version in my pom. Spark with scala 2.11.11 and my scala test plugin version for 2.10 . I changed the version to 2.11.11 . Now it is building :)